# Array creation with constants in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

I'm sure this has been asked here already but I can't locate the answer...
In c we have this:

```
#define COMMAND_ARGUMENTS_SIZE (3)
typedef struct
{
    unsinged char opcode; 
    unsigned char arguments[COMMAND_ARGUMENTS_SIZE];
} Command;
```

In c# we'd like this:

```
struct Command
{
    byte opcode;
    byte arguments[...];
}
```

The array sizes are in a state of flux and we have them used across several files. We'd like to keep the #define (but we know we can't....). This is a port and we're not about to do major rewrites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a constants utility class to hold the "define"-like directives in C#:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const int CommandArgumentsSize = 3;
}

struct Command
{
    byte opcode;
    byte[] arguments = new byte[Constants.CommandArgumentsSize];
}
```

Comment: This seems to make life simpler.. however you need a byte[] for 'arguments'.

Comment: You don't really *need* the class, but I think it helps keeping things in place. And thanks for the byte/byte[] type, I've fixed it.

Comment: @Gio - What do you mean you don't need a class for consts? You can't put them directly in the namespace nor outside the namespace.

Comment: You can put the constant in the same class/struct where it's used (in this case, Command), instead of having a class just for the constants. If this is the only place where it's going to be used, then I'd actually say it's better to do that than inside a "Constants" class. But if it's going to be used in multiple places, I'd prefer to have it in one place where we can easily change.

Comment: Personally, I would put the constant where it is most logical: In this case, it would be in `Command`, and I'd name the constant `ArgumentsSize`, thus allowing me to refer to it as `Command.ArgumentsSize`.

Answer (score 4):

Mark the type as "unsafe" and use a [fixed size buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx).

```
unsafe struct Command 
{ 
  const int CommandArgumentsSize = 3;
  byte opcode;
  fixed byte arguments[CommandArgumentsSize];
}
```

It is easy to get confused between the "fixed" declaration and the "fixed" statement. [See my article on the subject if this is confusing.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/27/what-s-the-difference-between-fixed-and-fixed.aspx)

Alternatively, if you only have three of them then I'd be inclined to:

```
struct Command 
{ 
  byte opcode;
  byte arg1;
  byte arg2;
  byte arg3;
}
```

Easy peasy, no messing around with crazy pointers. If there are only three of them, that's a good solution; if it's a 1000 byte struct then that might not be so hot.

Comment: `fixed` has to be before the type, not after.

Comment: I'm not thrilled about 'fixed' as it leaves me with 'unsafe' which I then have to propogate up the chain, and right now the guy who signs my check is looking at me funny because he wants it done N O W.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static class

```
static class Constants 
{
  public const int DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
}
```

It's generally a better idea to encapsulate such knowledge but something like this would not be awful as long as you don't put more than a few constants in there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `#define` use a `public const` in C#

```
 struct Command {
    public const int ArgumentSize = 3;
    byte opcode;
    byte[] arguments;
 }
```

Note: that you have "allocate" the byte array.  I would use a class that preallocates:

```
 class Command {
    public const int ArgumentSize = 3;
    public byte opcode;
    public byte[] arguments = new byte[ArgumentSize];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
unsafe struct Command
{
    const int CommandArgumentSize = 3;

    byte opcode;
    fixed byte arguments[CommandArgumentSize];
}
```

You have to allow unsafe code in your compiler to do this.

If you only want to use it for communication with some unmanaged code, using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]` should do the trick too.